# How can I get posts with latest comment by Laravel Eloqunt?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, relation

I can use following code to get posts with their comments:

```
Post::with('comments')->where('status', 'publish');
```

Now, how can I get posts with ONLY latest comment of each post?

Also, It would be great if there was a way to get post with first plus latest comment like how Instagram shows comments in home page!

[image: Instagram Comment Section]

Comment: .can you post your  model and controller ?

Answer (score 2):

try this to get last 5 commments :

```
 Post::with( ['comments' => function($c){
                $c->latest()->limit(5)->get() ;
            } ])->where('status', 'publish');
```

Answer (score 2):

This [article](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/) suggests in Post put:

```
public function latestComment()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Comment')->latest();
}
```

Then do:

```
$posts = Post::with('latestComment')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  Post::with(array('comments' => function($query) {
    $query->where('status', 'publish')
    $query->orderBy('comments', 'DESC');

  }))->get();
```

Comment: This is not correct! This query works on all comments. In other words if I add ->take(1) to above code it only shows 1 comment totally not one comment per post!